# Cannot compile a Java program command-line

Tags: java, command-line, compilation

I tried the following in cl:

`javac Main.java`

The shell gives an error that "javac" is not a recognized command.  I know for a fact I have the Java Platform installed.  What could be wrong?

(I use "cd" to set the directory first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javac is most likely not on the PATH, and you must give the full path in your command.

Comment: What do you mean? Typing in this? <code>javac C:/Users/......./Main.java</code> That did not work

Comment: No, `c:/path/to/jdk/bin/javac.exe Main.java`. But better is to add `c:/path/to/jdk/bin` to `%PATH%` environment variable so that you don't need to enter the full `javac` path everytime.

Comment: If you've got Java environment variables set up, you can also do something along the lines of `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe Main.java`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `/bin` folder to your environment variables.

[How do I set or change the PATH system variable?](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Comment: I followed the instructions for Vista (setting the PATH system variable to the directory of the src) I tried it again and it gave the same error

Comment: You need to restart windows after you edit the environment variable.

Comment: @Alan Not the location of the src, the location of javac. On windows probably something like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin

Comment: In windows, you need to restart. In linux you dont.

Comment: @zengr: this is not true. You just need to close all opened command prompt windows and reopen a new one. @Alan, it's `javac.exe`. If you don't have such file, you probably haven't installed [JDK](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/widget/jdk6.jsp) (for developers), but just [JRE](http://java.com) (for endusers).

Comment: though "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin\javac.exe" Main.java works

Comment: @zengr, the value of PATH is read by the CMD.EXE window when opened.  Hence all _new_ CMD.EXE windows will have the new PATH value.

Comment: @Alan Can you post the value you typed in "PATH" in the Environment Variables.